# useState to update h1 text color style in React isn't using the default state

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to figure out why the color style of my h1 isn't updating to use the default state. It works for my Randy Moss quote default state and works when I switch out the reference to an in-line reference to the color.

```
function App () {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState('Nobody controls me but my mama and God.');
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('#DE14F2');

  const updateQuote = () => {
    setQuote(
      Quotes[Math.floor(Quotes.length * Math.random())]
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1 style={{color: {textColor}}}>{quote}</h1>
      </div>
      <button onClick={updateQuote}>New Quote</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-sun-usrht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<h1 style={{color: {textColor}}}>{quote}</h1>
```

with

```
<h1 style={{color: textColor}}>{quote}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method:

```
<button onClick={() => updateQuote()}>New Quote</button>
```

also you need to change:

```
<h1 style={{color: textColor }}>{quote}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for offering the solution, but the onClick is properly calling the updateQuote function as is. The struggle I'm having is that when I render the h1 the first time I expect it to have the color of: #DE14F2 and instead it is just black text.

Comment: This might not change anything.

Comment: @mpc75 try with this `<h1 style={{color:  textColor }}>{quote}</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

For the colour issue, you need to change this way:

```
<h1 style={{ color: textColor }}>{quote}</h1>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-sun-usrht